SDEs and irreversibility in statistical mechanics
In statistical mechanics, the equations governing particle behavior are typically deterministic ordinary differential equations (ODEs). However, in real-life particle systems, these systems are never completely closed and are always subject to small external perturbations. I believe that these small disturbances may be significant and could greatly influence thermodynamic properties.
For instance, Poincaré's recurrence theorem presents a paradox: when a cup of water that is half hot and half cold mixes, does it not imply that the system could eventually return to a state that is half cold and half hot? I feel that the best resolution to this paradox is to point out that the potential for Poincaré recurrence would be disrupted by these small perturbations.
I propose that we can add a stochastic term to the ODEs governing particle behavior, transforming them into stochastic differential equations (SDEs). I anticipate that this SDE will exhibit the property that, as time approaches infinity, the solutions will converge to a steady-state distribution, thereby demonstrating irreversibility and resolving the apparent contradiction with Poincaré's theorem.
My question is: If this property holds, would it be beneficial for studying statistical mechanics? Are there current researchers investigating similar issues?
However, I must admit that I haven't fully grasped whether this idea is reasonable, as my knowledge of SDEs is quite limited. I wonder if it's common for an ODE, which initially exhibits chaotic behavior as time approaches infinity, to converge to a steady-state distribution after introducing a stochastic term. I find that if such a phenomenon exists, it would be very interesting.
Without introducing randomness, the existing explanations for the Poincaré recurrence paradox do not convince me. Even if the recurrence time is extremely long and thus unobservable in practice, this does not theoretically resolve the paradox. From a purely theoretical perspective, the influence of Poincaré recurrence should still manifest, yet I have not seen this addressed in the derivations of statistical mechanics. How does current mathematical theory handle this recurrence phenomenon within statistical mechanics?
In fact, I am uncertain about the extent to which modern mathematics can explain the irreversibility observed in the mixing of hot and cold water. The statistical mechanics texts I have found (such as those in this MO question: Where does a math person go to learn statistical mechanics?) are often too abstract, filled with complex formulas, and do not communicate how theory relates to real-world phenomena. Even if I understood the theorems, I would struggle to address any divergent questions. I feel there are too few who can balance theory with practical, accessible explanations that confront logical gaps instead of glossing over them. I feel like a blind person trying to grasp an elephant, which leaves me quite desperate.
Moreover, there seems to be an additional contradiction in the explanations for Poincaré recurrence. I previously encountered a conclusion in statistical mechanics stating that time averages can equal ensemble averages. Even with short-term observations of the system, we can consider our observation time sufficient to approximate infinite time averages. However, if the Poincaré recurrence time is extremely long, does this undermine the assertion that our observation time is “sufficiently long”?
Disclaimer: I used ChatGPT to help organize my thoughts and language for this post; I hope this is not considered cheating.
This question was originally posted on MO, but I expressed my ideas unclearly at that time. So I deleted that question and asked it again here on MSE.

Probably would receive a better answer on physics.SE (https://physics.stackexchange.com/), and likely similar questions have been asked there already. One of the better explanations I've come across of this stuff is David Tong's lectures on statistical physics: https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys/one.pdf

There is no paradox in the Poincaré's recurrence theorem. It is entirely possible that the water will demix (even in equilibrium). The probability of demixing (or getting arbitrarily close to any other state that is energetically possible) is non zero in the equilibrium distribution. But the probability of demixing is extremly small (think like $10^{-100}$).

Furthermore your reasoning about hot/cold is not reasonable, because temperature is (proportional to) the average expected kinetic energy of the system in equilibrium (and therefore is a "macro" variable), but poincares theorem only considers the microstate (not the "macro" state) of the system and has nothing to do with average values.

@QiaochuYuan Thank you; this is an excellent note. I also share the doubts raised in your question (https://mathoverflow.net/q/31464/166613) regarding the derivation of the exponential function in the Boltzmann distribution. Here, a Taylor expansion is applied to $S(E)$, assuming $\Omega(E) = (\exp \circ S)(E)$. However, we could choose alternative functions, decomposing $\Omega(E) = (f \circ g)(E)$ and expanding $g$, which would lead to different results. I find this answer (https://mathoverflow.net/a/31485/166613) quite reasonable.
